# How to center the entire div tag along with it's elements?

Tags: html, css, tags, margin, padding

I need to center the div tag and its elements. I've tried giving width and margin-left: auto; and margin-top: auto; but it doesn't work!

I need to center the div vertically.

HTML:

```
 <div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://twitter.com/login"><img src="images/twitter.png" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://quora.com"><img src="images/quora.png" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://youtube.com"><img src="images/youtube.png" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://web.whatsapp.com"><img src="images/whatsapp.png" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://shreydan.tumblr.com"><img src="images/tumblr.png" /></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.nav {
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #aed003;
}

.nav ul {
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 10px 0px;
}

.nav ul li {
  margin: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav ul li a {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px 10px;
}

.nav ul li a img {
  height: 50px;
  max-height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  max-width: 50px;
}
```

In it's current state:
[image]

It works now, thank you hungerstar and Nick R for the answers and thank you to others too.
@hungerstar : Aligning the div vertically: https://jsfiddle.net/e6aq6f1w/3/
@nick-r : Aligning the elements of div horizontally: https://jsfiddle.net/f4fjxxj8/

Comment: If your `.nav` element takes up the full width of the viewport, then it's working.

Comment: Nope. I only need to center align the elements of the div and the div vertically.

Comment: Trust me, your div is centered. That doesn't mean the inside elements will be also. If the DIV is taking up the full width of the viewport it's hard to see that that is actually what's going on, compare with [this JSFiddle example.](https://jsfiddle.net/e6aq6f1w/2/). You don't need `width: 100%;` for `.nav` as DIVs are block level elements and by default are 100% width. I believe your actual question is how to center the DIV's elements and not necessarily the DIV itself.

Comment: I need to center the div vertically!

Comment: I'm not sure what that means. So you want it centered in the middle of the page? The blue DIV in [my JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e6aq6f1w/2/) is centered horizontally, but you don't want that? Do you need something like the yellow DIV in [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/e6aq6f1w/3/)?

Comment: i want to bring the whole thing to the center of the page. Just like the yellow div!

Comment: @hungerstar Thank You for the answer! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, as the solutions to this question was answered by different people, here is the final solution:

[nick-r](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2470724/nick-r) : For aligning the elements of div in the center horizontally:

```
.nav ul {
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  text-align:center;
}

.nav ul li {
  margin: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  display:inline-block;
}

.nav ul li a {
  margin: 0px 10px;
}
```

[hungerstar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/804867/hungerstar) : For centering the div tag vertically:

```
.nav {
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #aed003;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `float:left` and replace it with `display:inline-block;`, then on the parent `ul` add `text-align:center` - https://jsfiddle.net/f4fjxxj8/

Comment: Did you add `display:inline-block;` to `.nav ul li` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use css `flexbox`. Add following css to `ul`.

```
.nav ul {
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
}
```

```css
.nav {
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #aed003;
}

.nav ul {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}

.nav ul li {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.nav ul li a img {
  height: 50px;
  max-height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  max-width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://twitter.com/login"><img src="images/twitter.png" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://quora.com"><img src="images/quora.png" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://youtube.com"><img src="images/youtube.png" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://web.whatsapp.com"><img src="images/whatsapp.png" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://shreydan.tumblr.com"><img src="images/tumblr.png" /></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove  `float: left;` from `.nav ul li a` and put `display: inline-block` in `.nav ul li`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution to vertically **and** horizontally centering and element in the middle of a page. You will need to use fixed positioning and translate.

```css
.nav {
  /* centering start */
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  /* centering end */
  display: inline;
  background-color: #aed003;
}
.nav ul,
.nav li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.nav ul {
  padding: 0 5px
}
.nav li {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 5px;
}
.nav ul li a img {
  display: block;
  max-height: 50px;
  max-width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="http://twitter.com/login">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/75x75?text=one">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="http://quora.com">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/75x75?text=two">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="http://youtube.com">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/75x75?text=three">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="http://web.whatsapp.com">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/75x75?text=four">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="http://shreydan.tumblr.com">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/75x75?text=five">
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```